# Java: constructor toma valores por defecto

Tags: java, poo

Tengo la siguiente clase Persona:

```
    public class Persona {
        private String nombre;
        private String dni;
        private int edad;
        
    public Persona(String nombre,String dni,int edad){
        nombre = this.nombre;
        dni = this.dni;
        edad = this.edad;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getDni() {
        return dni;
    }

    public void setDni(String dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Nombre: "+nombre+" Dni: "+dni+" Edad: "+edad;
    }
    
}
```

y esta otra clase Prueba:

```
    public class Prueba{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      
        Persona [] arrayPersona = new Persona[4];

        arrayPersona[0] = new Persona("Eric","40001023",23);
        arrayPersona[1] = new Persona("Talia","3399394",12);
        arrayPersona[2] = new Persona("Lucy","2365673",56);
        arrayPersona[3] = new Persona("Luis","64576745",33);

        for (int k=0;k<=3;k++){
            System.out.println(arrayPersona[k].toString());
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

al momento de imprimir cada elemento de mi array me sale lo siguiente:

```
Nombre: null Dni: null Edad: 0

Nombre: null Dni: null Edad: 0

Nombre: null Dni: null Edad: 0

Nombre: null Dni: null Edad: 0
```

No sé porque me muestra null. A ver si alguno me puede ayudar del porque de este error, gracias.

Comment: Hola,puedes explicar exactamente que quieres hacer?

Comment: es que desde mi persepectiva quieres tener una lista que contenga personas no se si este en lo correcto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está en el constructor de la clase `Persona` porque tienes la asignación de las variables invertida.

Modifica el constructor de la siguiente manera:

```
public Persona(String nombre,String dni,int edad){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.dni = dni;
    this.edad = edad;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma para que no te líes con los métodos constructores es poner diferente nombre de variable, si aún no estás acostumbrado a usar la palabra reservada "this"